# How to remove the vertical space before one particular chapter tittle?

Tags: chapters

How to raise the whole chapter higher? the other chapters should not be modified, I just want to upload the first chapter.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{\makebox[\linewidth]{ABSTRACT}}%\chapter*{\centering Abstract}
El principal mecanthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis intro

\section{Exp}
this Exp SECTION

\chapter{ETAPA2}
\label{cap:experimental}
this intro

\section{Exp2}
this Exp SECTION

\end{document}
```

i want this result:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at `titlesec`.

Comment: @JouleV i am nob in latex, please

Comment: All the chapters or only  the abstract?

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda only the abstract

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `titlesec` package as suggested by @JouleV:

```
{
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\filcenter\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{40pt}
\chapter*{ABSTRACT}
}
```

The complete code

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
{
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\filcenter\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{40pt}
\chapter*{ABSTRACT}
}
%\chapter*{\makebox[\linewidth]{ABSTRACT}}%\chapter*{\centering Abstract}
El principal mecanthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis introthis intro

\section{Exp}
this Exp SECTION

\chapter{ETAPA2}
\label{cap:experimental}
this intro

\section{Exp2}
this Exp SECTION

\end{document}
```