# How to change the font type and size of chapter title?

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters, fontsize

Right now I am getting my chapter title in the following font that is big-sized and bold:

[image]

However, I want to change it to the following format, which is regular size, normal text, with regular font type, and is centered:
[image]

I just mean the "Introduction" text in the above figures. Here is my general code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1.5in]{geometry}
...
\begin{document}
...
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\begin{center}
INTRODUCTION
\end{center}
Hi there! I want my chapter text and the section text to be the same default font
...
\end{document}
```

Edit: Now that I have used the code recommended by Hafid Boukhoulda, I am able to change the font, but I am facing a different problem, that my page number starts on a blank page, and the introduction text starts in the next page. If it is clear. My code is:

```
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\centering}{}{0pt}{}
\titlelabel{}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{10pt}


\begin{document}
\setlength{\headheight}{50pt} %to note where the header lies.
\setlength{\headsep}{15pt} %to set the distance between header and the first line after it.

....

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\begin{center}
\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\end{center}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look to [this may be related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476881/how-to-remove-the-vertical-space-before-one-particular-chapter-tittle/477038#477038) and its answer.

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda Naah, that code only changed the vertical space. Did it change the font type and size?

Comment: If you can enclose the modifications  for a particular chapter inside a `group` e.g `{}`  the original format will be restored automatically. In that sens the two questions may be somehow similar

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you asking how to change the format or how to go back. Where is the "unnecessary format change." (In intro or in toc) ? As usual, please help us to help you by editing your question to add a complete compilable MWE, even if it is not completly "working".

Comment: Take a look at this answer to another question. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62711/9632

Comment: @Jhor, thanks. I changed it a bit. Is it clear now? I don't want that default chapter title font to appear, but want the chapter font type and size to be like the regular default paragraph text, if that is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage[rm,tiny]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\centering}{}{0pt}{}

\titlelabel{}

\begin{document}

%\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter{The chapter title in normal font}
\section{The section title in normal font}

The paragraph in normal font

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Hafid, thanks so much, that works. But I had two minor problems. First, it skipped a whole page (page number 1 set above in the code is in first page which is blank, and the introduction started from the next page). And, second, the vertical space was too much both above and below "Introduction." Could you fix this please? Thanks :)

Comment: I guess I kind of realized that I can change vertical space by playing around with those -50, 40 numbers. But the page number starting in the previous page is still there. My code is given in the editted question details.

Comment: Also, I realize that the page number in the Intro page is in the bottom, but I set it on top for the entire document (all page but intro page has it at the bottom, the intro page starts at 2)